# Has anyone researched which current/former rules changes would have been subjected to the REINS Act?

Tags: united-states, congress, house-of-representatives, citizen-activism

Has anyone researched which currently in-force legislation would have been affected by the REINS Act, had it the REINS act been in force at the time?  I'm thinking like Clean Air Act, Clean Water Act, OSHA rules, etc.  I ask because I am planning to ask my rep about his (yes) vote on the [REINS Act](https://www.congress.gov/bill/115th-congress/house-bill/26).  This bill, which passed the House in January 2017, would require congressional review for any "major rule" passed by a federal agency. A "major rule" has an annual effect on the economy of $100 million, may increase costs for consumers, or may significantly adversely affect competition, employment, etc for corporations.  A number of amendments to add exceptions were rejected, for example:

1. An exemption for restrictions on green house gas emissions
2. An exemption for rules that may reduce incidence of cancer, asthma attacks, premature mortality, or respiratory disease in children
3. An exemption for rules pertaining to the protection of public health or safety
4. An exemption for rules to reduce the amount of lead in public drinking water
5. An exemption for rules pertaining to workplace health and safety

See [here](http://www.kentucky.com/news/politics-government/article44073501.html) for the impetus for the Act - a Kentucky voter was upset that Lexington was forced to comply with a consent decree to overhaul the city's sewer system for violating the Clean Water Act (basically, raw sewage was contaminating the town's water supply).  He proposed a bill to his local rep and they ran with it (there's a story in The Hill about this, but I can only post two links).

Comment: I think the 'legislation' in the title ought to be 'rule change' and you ought to include a question in the body.